# Property 'valHooks' does not exist on type 'JQueryStatic'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am in the process of upgrading my javascript code to TypeScript and I am facing issue with the following javascript function.

```
var PreserveLinebreakInTextArea = function () {
           $.valHooks.textarea = { get: function (elem) { return elem.value.replace(/\r?\n/g, "\r\n"); } };
        }
```

I am using the above method for preserving the line break in text area control. When I use this method in typescript file, I got the following error,

[image]

Any suggestion to fix this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can either write:

```
  var PreserveLinebreakInTextArea = function () {
       $['valHooks'].textarea = { get: function (elem) { return elem.value.replace(/\r?\n/g, "\r\n"); } };
  }
```

to keep `tsc` happy or you can extend `JQueryStatic` interface like this

```
interface JQueryStatic {
    valHooks: any;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: This saved me on $.hubConnection() for SignalR. I was able to do $['hubConnection']() instead. Good reminder.

Comment: This saved me on jQuery.validator.addMethod()